# Influence function of conditional quantile

Tags: functional-data-analysis, influence-function

I'm trying to derive the influence function of the estimand $\Psi$

$$\Psi(P) = P(Y > y | X = x)$$

Following tutorials for deriving the influence function of the average treatment effect [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.01706.pdf). Has anyone seen this derived anywhere?

Comment: is $\Psi$ pathwise differentiable?

Comment: It should be right? At least P(Y >y) is?